# 'Et viola' misspelling or inside joke?

Tags: is-it-a-word, jokes

#### Question

Is `et viola [sic]`(spelled like this intentionally) just a misspelling of `et voila` or is it an actual word, or perhaps an inside joke (not just a one-off thing)?

#### Background

Based on this [answer by Bread](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/446798/71848), there has been some discussion about the idiom `et viola [sic]`. The discussion stems from this phrase on [vocabulary.com's entry for `pate`](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pate):

> Your pate is the top of your head, but say it with a French accent **et viola**!

One side argues that this is a misspelling of `et voila`, which is listed by [Merriam Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voil%C3%A0).

The other side insists it's an inside joke, referring to [the following article by BBC Radio 4](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/today/reports/arts/violajokes_20041202.shtml):

[image]

It is my observation that this article is about the viola, an instrument in [the violin family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_family), which might explain the word play ([a viola is a type of violin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola)).

#### Research

I have searched for more examples of its use on the internet, but most of the results are eating establishments with this name. I have not been able to find another occurrence of `et viola` as a joke, or used in another way.

I have also looked at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=et+viola&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cet%20viola%3B%2Cc0) and found that `et viola` was used in English in the 1800s. The peak isn't very high (in comparison to more prevalent terms), but it does seem to be something.

In my view, the research is inconclusive in stating definitively if `et viola` has been used repeatedly over the years or if it's just a misspelling, hence this question.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=viola%21&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cviola%20%21%3B%2Cc0 https://www.google.com/search?q=viola+jokes&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&oq=viola+jokes&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2j69i60j0.3892j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola_jokes I guess you need to be a little more sophisticated to get it. Also, you misquoted Vocabulary.com.

Comment: **voilà** is spelled with the accent over the "a" (a-grave) because it is a French loanword. Without it, there would be no distinctive rising tone. Vocabulary.com just made a banal typo. There is no joke "et viola" unless you deliberately want to make a pun but then you would need context. Not my downvote.

Comment: Doesn't it seem a bit unlikely that *all* of the examples of "et viola" are  inside jokes? I don't really understand why you've found the research inconclusive, rather than finding that it points to the conclusion that "et viola" has been used as a joke and has also occurred as a misspelling of "et voila".

Comment: @sumelic I have only found one example of it as a joke (the BBC one linked by Bread). Unfortunately I cannot see the ones the Ngram refers to. It's not unlikely that some of those are misspellings, but how do you explain those peaks in the 19th century? It also doesn't correlate with the viola jokes a few comments above, those list the 18th century, whereas the Ngrams are flat until 1811.

Comment: Always, always check the Ngram results (the actual instances reported) at the bottom of the page. I'm not going to do that for you :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA that seems to answer it, most of them are names or Latin. I didn't know about the links at the bottom, thanks for telling me. :)

Comment: The BBC article is not 'about violins', it is about the viola, a different member of the string section which other orchestral players traditionally make rude jokes about. The title is itself a pun on the common mis-spelling of the French phrase 'Et voilà'.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for the reply, I rephrased the part about the BBC article. The actual question, however, is not about that article, but rather about the pun in general. Take for example the Vocabulary.com entry, is that also a pun (it's not about the violin family) or is it a genuine misspelling.

Comment: related: [Interjection “et voilà”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3812/interjection-et-voil%C3%A0) And only 23 results for [viola](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=viola) in EL&U's search engine, as far as I can tell they all refer to the musical instrument or the flower.

Comment: Good to see that the comments have all been deleted under Bread's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mari-Lou A's helpful comment about [checking the ngram references](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22et+viola%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&nfpr=1&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&ei=UwwCW_nGBcywsAH3gbuoDA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1920&bih=974&dpr=1), I think it safe to conclude that the peaks (for me, the main reason to think it wasn't a misspelling on vocabulary.com) are caused by the following (unlikely) reasons:

> An author with `et viola` in the name: ([Alberti et Viola](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&ei=cQ0CW922DKGMmgW4wrGwCw&q=%22Alberti+et+Viola%22&oq=%22Alberti+et+Viola%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10074.11463.0.11667.6.5.1.0.0.0.199.681.1j3.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.1.190...33i160k1.0.Uz2abB1Oq5M)).
>
> Books in the English corpus which are (partially) written in Latin. Most of the other results, mostly compilations of prose.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question whether *et viola* is a misspelling or a (corny) pun by the editors of *vocabulary.com*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA fair enough, consider it a partial answer for now. Tell me if you want to add something, then I'll turn it into a community wiki answer (or you could post a separate answer if you'd like).

Comment: I'll pass. For me, it's a non-issue.